# Getting Hadoop cluster nodes list in YARN application

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm writing YARN application, which must run some java code on each cluster node. I've started at [Writing YARN applications](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html), and then, after facing too many spaces in the example, used [this github project](https://github.com/blrunner/yarn-beginners-examples) as base for my application.

As I've found after digging into exapmle's **ApplicationMaster** usage, I can use specific **org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.ContainerRequest**'s constructor, to obtain application container upon specific host, but I need cluster nodes list to request container on every machine.

After searching by this question, I've found that parsing yarn-site.xml isn't right way of obtaining cluster machines URL's, but this information is available from **org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClient.getClusterNodeLabels()**, but Set, returned by this method, contains 0 records.

I'm shure, that cluster, my jar is running on, consists of few nodes, so I don't understand, what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I use remote debug, when running, my jar.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `getNodeReports()` from the `YarnClient`?

Comment: @Serhiy org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.NodesListManager$UnknownNodeId cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.NodeIdPBImpl. I cannot provide you with full stack trace because comment characters amount is limited.

Comment: I got that exception because `YarnClient` wasn't started just initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way of doing it is to use [YarnClient#getNodeReports](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html#getNodeReports(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.NodeState...)). To get complete list just provide all possible states as parameter:

```
yarnClient.getNodeReports(NodeState.values())
```